# Create failed for database , SMO,C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, smo

I am trying to create a new database programmatically using SMO (c#).

I am working on SQL Server 2005. This is the code :

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
Database newDB = new Database(sqlServer, databaseName);
newDB.Create();
```

I get the exception :

> "Create failed for database."

What could be the problem and how can I create a new DB?
thanks...

Comment: Any other error information, say in SQL Server logs? The inner .net exception should show what SQL Server threw as an error

Comment: I was editing, sorry. And the .net inner exception?

Comment: @marc_s - yes , the user has the permitions , i can create the DB in the sql management studio.

Comment: So you connect with exactly the same username+password as above?

Comment: @gbn this is the exception - Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Failed {"Create failed for Database 'TempDB'. "}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this: with a sysadmin user, everything works just fine. With a "normal" user, I get the same error as you do.

Try this:

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
Database newDB = new Database(sqlServer, databaseName);

try
{
   newDB.Create();
} 
catch(Exception exc) 
{
   string msg1 = exc.Message;

   if(exc.InnerException != null)
   {
       string msg2 = exc.InnerException.Message;

       if(exc.InnerException.InnerException != null)
       {
           string msg3 = exc.InnerException.InnerExceptionMessage;
       }
   }
}
```

Do you see a `msg2` and a `msg3` ?? What do they say???

When using a user without the necessary permission, my `msg3` is **very clear**:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Comment: it was my embarrassing error , i am sorry to bothered you all ....
i tried to create a database which already existed....:( but you helped me to see the inner exception ...thank you very much , you really helped me !!!

Comment: @N.D.: it helps to checkout the `.InnerException` entries, too!