# How to create database using SMO and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have a program made in WPF with C#, this will be installed on many computers.

The program needs a connection to the local database (SQL Server Express) because it works offline. There is a central server where data is collected after a sync using Sync Framework.

Everything works fine, synchronization is performed successfully and without complications.

The problem arises when wanting to install the program on a new computer; the requirement which calls for the program is that you have installed SQL Server Express with an instance called `VYSICO`.

When run for the first time, the program should create the database called `Vysico`, for this I am trying to run a command with SMO; this is my code:

```
ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection();
srvConn.ServerInstance = ".\\" + instanceName;
srvConn.LoginSecure = false;  
srvConn.Login = sqlServerLogin;
srvConn.Password = password;

Server server = new Server(srvConn);

Database db = new Database(server, "Vysico");
db.Create();
```

Wanting to instantiate Database, throws me the following error:

> setparent failed for database Vysico

I searched the net a long time but nothing solves my problem, I hope you can help me. I thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create failed for database , SMO,C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783229/create-failed-for-database-smo-c)

Comment: Check your inner exception to see if there are more details associated with the error.

Comment: I'm accessing user sa, tried to exceptions answered in another question and this is what I get:

msg1: > setparent failed for database Vysico

msg2: > Method Not Found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetDatabaseConnection(System.String)'.

msg3 remains null